# how can I import npm modules in meteor for once in my project instead of importing on every page?

Tags: meteor, npm

I have to import npm modules in my existing project of Meteor. I am using some modules on each page and in meteor I am forces to import npm module on each page.Is there any common page where I import modules once and use it in my application throughout?

Comment: Can you provide a small snippet of how you're actually doing it?

Comment: I am migrating my whole application to 1.4 and found doing this is tedious. I just put import on each js file where I have to use that particular module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you must `import` modules (regardless if they are npm packages, atmosphere packages, or other files in your project) in every JavaScript file in Meteor is because you have the [`ecmascript`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/ecmascript.html) package installed.

This wonderful package allows you to take advantage of all the great new ECMAScript 2015 (or ES6) features (eg. arrow functions, classes, constants, block scoping​, etc.). One such feature (and the one that you are talking about)  that it also includes is modules.

In ES6, modules are a built-in construct where units of reusable code are scoped at the file level such that there is exactly one module per file and one file per module.  This means that in order to use any piece of code defined outside of a file you must first import it. This is very similar to `import` in Java and `#include` in C++, but subtly different.  You can learn more about ES6 modules [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

Long story short, there are tons of advantages  to the new spec, however if you wish to revert back to the global nature of pre-ES6, you can simply remove the `ecmascript` package from your meteor project, follow the [original folder structure​ guidelines](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories),  and you will no longer have to import modules in every file..

Comment: Its good but this makes a bunch of import codes on each page which I want to avoid.

Comment: I understand, look at the last paragraph of my answer, you dont have to use it. You can remove that package and pull your files out if the `import` folder and just follow the [original meteor folder structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).  Then no import code is required.

Comment: Exactly  Actually we have developed an enterprise application on meteor 1.2 and its functions are completed about more than 80% now we are migrating to 1.3 so to use npm modules. now redesign structure while using import is getting much tedious. Is is OK with security purpose and performance not to use import folder?? If using import can lead to better performance I would like to take that pain. If it doesn't help with that its better as it is. can you suggest plaese? thank you.

Comment: I doubt there is any performance gain and there is certainly no security impact.  I think it just makes your code more explicit by defining in each module (file) what external things you are referencing.